# If I am there, I am not there, and if I am not there, I am there. Where am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

The range of the valid answers is absolutely anything, meaning that there is no limitations in valid answers.

Comment: Aren't you risking this question being tagged /marked as topic too broad?

Comment: If he really meant what he say, and there's no actual 'lateral-thinking behind this, then probably yeah... 'meaning that there is no limitations in valid answers.' Means there will be actually no correct answer, because most of them are valid anyway.

Comment: Please wait a bit (days) to green checkmark an answer, specially when you state the riddle is open ended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The place where you are is:

> (not there).

- If I am there, I am not there:

> If you are (not there), you are not there.

- If I am not there, I am there:

> If you are not (not there), you are there.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Replace "Not There" with Liverpool (a random place). "If I am there, I am Liverpool, and if I am Liverpool, I am there. Where am I?" What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Replace "not there" with "in Liverpool" and you're fine. "Not there" is an adverbial phrase, while "Liverpool" is just a noun, so you can't just swap them out and expect it to work.

Comment: But you'd need that "in" or other preposition: *If I am there, I am **in** "Not There", and if I am **at** "Not There", I am there*. Otherwise, you *are* the place known as "Not There".

Answer (score 16):

You are

> here.

Since

> if you are here, you are not there, and if you are there, you are not here.

Comment: Simple and nice! Great answer.

Answer (score 7):

You are:

> inside a [Schrödinger box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat).

Comment: How could that make sense?

Answer (score 7):

You are

> where you are not

because

> you are the word 'not'

indeed

> if you are not there, you're definitely there, and conversely.

also

> if you are present, you are absent. but if you are not present, you are present

Answer (score 3):

You could be in either 
Thère, 79170 Périgné, France
or
There, Assam 788832, India
but travel between the two could be difficult
Look them up in google maps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're

> nowhere

Then maybe you're

> on a [Nowhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_(event)) festival :D

Which is quite straight.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the language of the OP, and broadens the scope of some other "similar" replies I thought of making:

If you are

> absent

then you are not

> present

And if you are not

> present

then you are

> absent

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Absence

Because

> If your absence is there, you are not there.

And

> If your absence is not there, you are there.

Answer (score 0):

You might be

> at an other place

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may well be

> Here

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation? Answers without explanations are likely to be deleted.